# How can I use a button to show more posts?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to make a page with posts. And then when i press a button it shows more posts

```
$start = 0;
  $end = 5;
  $slice = array_slice($postid_array, $start, $end);
  if(isset($_POST['load_more']) && is_numeric($_POST['load_more'])) {
    $load_more = $_POST['load_more'];
    if($load_more > 0) {
      $start = ($load_more * 5) + 1;
    }
    $end = $start + 4;
    $slice = array_slice($postid_array, $start, $end);
  }
```

This is what I got, I use ajax to increase $load_more with 1:

```
 var clicked = 0;
function countClicks(){
  clicked += 1;
  var nb_clicked = clicked;
  console.log(nb_clicked);
  $.ajax({
    url: "../home/posts.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "load_more="+nb_clicked,
    success: function(responseText) {
      $(".posts").append(responseText)
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("ajax error");
    }
  })
}
```

But instead of getting 5 more posts. I get 10, and when i click again it gives me 15.

I hope this is enough information.

Thank you!

Comment: The code on `load_more.php` is `javascript`

Comment: whats this? `$load_more = $_POST['load_more'];
   $load_more = 1;` Is it for test? And it should be 0 at first time, not 1.

Comment: Why do you set `$load_more` to 1 immediately after reading the POST value?  You're now ignoring the POST value.  Also, you're checking if the value is `> 0` immediately after setting it to `1`.  One is *always* greater than zero.  Also, in `load_more.php` you are trying to use JavaScript code as if it were PHP code.  This is resulting in a variety of syntax errors and that script just isn't going to work at all.  You have a *variety* of strange problems here, you may want to take a step back and try again from the beginning.

Comment: @vaso123 this is indeed for a test

Comment: @David I made a mistake in my post. Already edited it. Wrong piece of code added :(

Comment: here: `array_slice($postid_array, $start, $end);` - the 3rd param isn't the `$end`, but the length/size. This is why you get more and more. So the third param should always be 5 in your case. [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: @Jeff Thank you, that was the problem, :)

Comment: @Jeff ah crud, I just got done writing an answer and you already nailed it.

Comment: @Randall I should have written an answer then. It's alright, you nailed it,too!

Comment: and move this `clicked += 1;` to the success function. First time if it is 1, load more will be 1 * 5 + 1 = 6.

Comment: Sometimes its easier to pop the solution in a comment when its really just one line of code that was wrong ;) So, a lengthly writeup isn't needed.

Comment: @AnnedeGraaff It also would be better/easier to already filter the posts coming from your database via 'LIMIT'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st , you doing massive operation twice (array_slice) ... do 1st checks , 2nd splice .

2nd , is mistake - 3rd param of array_slice is LENGTH , not offset2 , or so.

so don't do

```
$end = $start + 4;
```

it's just 5 .

so best code . ( of course in your styling )

```
$start = 0;
$LENGTH = 5;
if(isset($_POST['load_more']) && is_numeric($_POST['load_more'])) {
    $load_more = $_POST['load_more'];
    if($load_more > 0) {
       $start = $load_more * $LENGTH;
    }
}
$slice = array_slice($postid_array, $start, $LENGTH);
```